# startxwin: command not found

Tags: linux, cygwin

I am trying to enable X11 forwarding on my cygwin.. And I was following this [tutorial](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~csadmin/wiki/index.php/Using_Cygwin_for_X11_Forwarding).

Whenever I do `startxwin`, I always get this error -

```
root@ubuntu-dyn-cassandra-50686:~# startxwin
startxwin: command not found
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: My guess is, you missed installing a package from the X11 sub-list (second to last step in the installation instructions).

Comment: I downloaded everything, all the subpackages.. I just checked it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ which startxwin
```

This should tell you that startxwin is here:
/usr/bin/startxwin

If it's not, then Joseph R's comment is probably correct and you don't have the package installed.

Comment: `which` searches a user's path for an executable of the name passed. The OP's error message means that, for whatever reason, `startxwin` is not in the path. Since we already know this, running `which` is not going to tell us anything new. Perhaps `locate startxwin` would be a better choice.